# How can I use microk8s with newer Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-multi-stage-build, microk8s

I'm currently running [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) in it's stable form (v1.12.0) on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. It comes with a Docker 17.03.2-ce, which lacks support for [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), added in Docker 17.05. [The microk8s documentation advises not to use any other Docker on the system](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/blob/master/docs/dockerd.md) (at least as long as AppArmor is on).

Is there a way to run microk8s with a newer version of Docker, so that I can use the multistage build feature, without risking the security of my system?

Answer (score 0):

One person [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/166) found a way to use microk8s with system docker. You can disable microk8s docker and use system's so there would not be clash.

Answer (score 0):

I think forcing microk8s to use other parts of your host system runs contradictory to its principle, which is isolated fully independent local kube cluster.
In your case, i would separate image building by utilizing your local docker with multistage support from the docker runtime used by microk8s.

Comment: But that contradicts the advice from their website of not having another Docker installed in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I guess i misunderstood their documentation, i thought as long as you have apparmor enabled then another dockerd running is not compatible.

Comment: I end up using the latest microk8s from the edge channel.